# Prove $C(t)$ varies in an absolutely continuous way

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, polyhedra

Prove that there exists an absolutely continuous function $v(\cdot): I → R$ such that for any $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $s,t\in [0,T]$,
 $$|dist (y, C(s)) − dist (y, C(t))| ≤ |v(s) − v(t)|$$ for all $s,t\in [0,T]$, where $C(t) := \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n|⟨a(t), x⟩ \leq b(t)\}$,
$a(t)$ and $b(t)$ are two absolutely continuous functions on $[0,T]$.

I was thinking to split it into some cases as follows

$\bullet$ Case 1: If $y\in C(s)$ and $y\in C(t)$ then this case is obviously.

$\bullet$ Case 2: If $y\notin C(s)$ or $y\notin C(t)$ then we have to split it into three cases
\begin{eqnarray}\label{d:1}
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\langle a(s),x\rangle >b(s)\\ 
\langle a(t),x\rangle \le b(t)
\end{matrix}\right.
\mbox{ or }
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\langle a(s),x\rangle \le b(s)\\ 
\langle a(t),x\rangle > b(t)
\end{matrix}\right.
\mbox{ or }
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\langle a(s),x\rangle > b(s)\\ 
\langle a(t),x\rangle > b(t)
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{eqnarray}